# Gradle update git submodules

Tags: git, gradle, groovy, git-submodules

I have a gradle project that's divided into submodules. It's not very convienient to execute `git submodule update --init` every time I need to build the project with latest sources, so I was wondering if there's a known way to create a gradle task that does that? Maybe there's an existing plugin? Unix and windows compatibility would be nice.

**UPDATE AFTER ANSWERED**

As **@VonC** stated [ajoberstar/gradle-git](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git) does the job.

Here's the configuration I ended up with

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:1.6.0'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'org.ajoberstar.grgit'

task submodulesUpdate(type:Exec) {
  description 'Updates (and inits) git submodules'
  commandLine 'git', 'submodule', 'update', '--init', '--recursive'
  group 'Build Setup'
}

task build

build.dependsOn submodulesUpdate

// ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As in [this pull request](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-client-java/pull/220/files), you could try and add a gradle task doing the submodule init for you.
That would depend and use [`ajoberstar/gradle-git`](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git).

```
task submodulesUpdate(type:Exec) {
    description 'Updates (and inits) git submodules'
    commandLine 'git', 'submodule', 'update', '--init', '--recursive'
    group 'Build Setup'
}
```